# Laravel 4 DatabaseSeed.php throws class not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have tried so much to get this database seed to work but I still get `Class 'Account' not found` even though I have namespaced where I should.

There error is thrown when running php artisan db:seed on `$accountOut = Account::create(array(` where Account is what is throwing the error. Am stating the using incorrectly? If I were to remove all the namespacing I have no issues at all.

My Account.php file:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class Account extends \Eloquent {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'account';

/**public function user()
{
    return $this-belongsTo('User');
}*/
}
```

My seed file:

```
<?php

use App\Models;

class TransactionSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{
    DB::table('transaction')->delete();
    DB::table('account')->delete();

    $accountOut = Account::create(array(
        'name'    => 'Checking',
        'origin'  => 'Bank'
    ));

    $accountIn = Account::create(array(
        'name'    => 'Stuff',
        'origin'  => 'Expense'
    ));

    $adminUser  = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findByLogin('admin@admin.com');

    Transaction::create(array(
        'account_id_in'   => $accountIn->id,
        'account_id_out'    => $accountOut->id,
        'amount'    => 300.00
    ));

}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel really stupid but instead of calling out `use App\Models` you would call out `use App\Models\Account` and it works as it should.

Then remember to run `php composer.phar dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues and prefixing my classes with the namespace operator solved them.

Try `\Account`

Comment: Still same error. It is a Symfony error still throwing on the same line after I put in `\Account` replacing `Account`

Comment: If I change `\Account` to `$accountOut = \App\Models\Account::create(array(` it works. So what it seems like is the use statement is being ignored.